# My regular expression does not take the second number

Tags: python, regex

I have this string:

```
field = 1400 x 3524
```

I want to take these numbers into two seperate variables so I can perform multiplication. This is how I do it:

```
num1 = re.match("(\d{3,4})(?= x)", field).group(1)
num2 = re.match("(?<=x )(\d{3,4})", field).group(1)
```

I works with the first number, but the second number comes out as a `NoneType`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not combine that into one expression…? `(\d+)\s*x\s*(\d+)`

Comment: Your second pattern fails because you need to use `re.search` instead of `re.match`

Comment: or you can just use `field.split(' x ')`

Comment: It is a too common, frequent and well-known issue: `re.match` only returns a match if it is at the start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = 'field = 1400 x 3524'
>>> m = re.findall( r'\d+', a )
>>> m
['1400', '3524']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`re` module [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) states that:

> Note that patterns which start with positive lookbehind assertions
>   will not match at the beginning of the string being searched; you will
>   most likely want to use the search() function rather than the match()
>   function

In your case that means you should do:

```
import re
field = "1400 x 3524"
num2 = re.search("(?<=x )(\d{3,4})", field).group(0)
print(num2) # 3524
```

Note that here beyond changing `match` to `search` I also changed `group(1)` to `group(0)`

Comment: don't overcomplicate things =)

Comment: It is true about what you say the manual says about positive lookbehind and if we were dong `re.match("(?<=x )(\d{3,4})", "x 3524")`, it would fail, i.e. we would need to do `re.search`. But the problem here was bigger than that in that even without using lookbehind, re.match would have failed because we were looking for the second integer, which was not at the beginning of the string. In other words, `re.match("(?:x )(\d{3,4})", field).group(1)` would have failed also.